# QGIS not showing complete data

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile that contains a road network. A while ago I could easily see the whole of my country.

There is no filter and every and the table contains all rows.

When displaying the file in Alteryx, it shows the complete layer.

What could be wrong with QGIS?

Comment: Have you loaded the data in a new project? If so, what happens?

Comment: a screenshot of the entire QGIS window would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem may be caused by an incorrect projection of the project. By “incorrect” I mean that your current projection may not be suitable for displaying your current data. For example, try displaying data geographically located in a UTM 42 zone with a UTM 5 projection.

**Try changing the projection of your project (not data!) to WGS 84 and retest.**

Comment: Thank you very much, changing it to GK3 solved the problem!

Comment: @Konrad Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.